# variable variables in php with mysql_result

Tags: php, mysql, variables

this is my problem:

```
echo "SELECT * FROM fornitori_elatos WHERE NomeFornitore = '".${mysql_result($elenco_fornitori,$k,"NomeFornitore")}."';";
```

generate this error:

> PHP Fatal error:Function name must be a string

can you help me?

Comment: What is that trying trying to do anyway?

Comment: I don't know what you're trying to do there, but it looks like a really bad idea.

Comment: "How to write Unmaintainable Code" is a parody, not a manual.

Comment: This seems a bit of an unorthodox way to do this and it saves nothing and probably doesn't help legibility of your code.

Comment: I don't get that error running that same block of code

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
echo "SELECT * FROM fornitori_elatos WHERE NomeFornitore = '".mysql_result($elenco_fornitori,$k,"NomeFornitore")."';";
```

Comment: i need to change the variable name!

Comment: like:
echo "SELECT * FROM fornitori_elatos WHERE NomeFornitore = '".$spicer."';";

Comment: echo "SELECT * FROM fornitori_elatos WHERE NomeFornitore = '".$ciccio."';";
echo "SELECT * FROM fornitori_elatos WHERE NomeFornitore = '".$lallo."';";